# uploading png files in WAMP

Tags: php, upload, png

I am trying to upload files using PHP and WAMP.  I am using a form and a PHP script.  When I upload a .jpg file everything works correctly.  When a try to upload a .png version of the same image the $FILES array is empty even though the file name is shown on the form.

BTW the two file being uploaded differ only in file extension (.jpg and .png) and both files display correctly in photoshop.

Comment: Both files might also differ in size and png might be larger than the max_upload_size or post_max_size.

Comment: I see `$FILES`, which should be `$_FILES`. Make sure `$_FILES['file_input_name']['type']`, or `$_FILES['file_input_name']['type'][i]` for multiple files, is correct, as well as `$_FILES['file_input_name']['size']`, or `$_FILES['file_input_name']['size'][i]`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the file type .png allowed? For example, 
    $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["type"] == "image/png"

Comment: Sorry i meant $_FILES.  In the processing PHP script I included a print_r call with the $_FILES array.  The array was empty.